# Code Review: Trying to get popular categories

Tags: collection, code-analysis

On a main category page there is a section for "popular ranges" where a range is a different sub category.

A simplified version of my category structure is:

```
root
|-Bathrooms
|--Sinks
|--Cabinets
|-Bedrooms
|--Lights
|--Beds
|-Ranges
|--Deor
|--Puro
```

Products will belong to multiple categories.

The below code is designed to get the popular ranges of products for the current sub-categories. The category has a landing-page style template and has `is anchor` set as no (so no products will be shown on the main category pages).

To clarify, the below code is getting the popular products for the current sub-categories, checking which range categories the products are in, and showing those range categories.

For example, Multiple Deor products have been sold in the Bathroom Sinks page, but no Puro products at all have been sold. So on the Bathroom page I want to show only the Deor Category.

```
//11 = ranges category
$ranges = array_flip(explode(',', Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(11)->getChildren()));
foreach($ranges as $key => $range) {
    $ranges[$key] = 0;
}
//list of popular products for current sub-categories
$products = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection') 
                ->addOrderedQty()
                ->joinField(
                    'category_id', 'catalog/category_product', 'category_id', 
                    'product_id = entity_id', null, 'left'
                )
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                ->setOrder('ordered_qty', 'desc')
                ->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('in' => explode(',', $_category->getChildren())));
//Work out popular range category
foreach($products as $product) {
    foreach($product->getCategoryIds() as $cat_id) {
        if(array_key_exists($cat_id, $ranges)) {
            $ranges[$cat_id]++;
        }
    }
}
//sort range categories so popular first
asort($ranges);
//remove ranges that have not been used
foreach($ranges as $key => $value) {
    if ($value < 1) {
        unset($ranges[$key]);
    }
}
//only want 4 categories
array_slice($ranges, 0, 4, true);

//fetch our range categories
if(count($ranges) > 0) {
    $rangesCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
                            ->getCollection()
                            ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in'=>array_keys($ranges)));
}

//another foreach loop showing range names, images and links.
//...
```

This code has a LOT of foreach loops. Is there a way to refactor all of the above to reduce the number of loops and make the whole thing a lot more efficient?

#### edit

Made the first block of code more efficient (instead of iterating of several categories, we are getting the parent category and getting child ids, then setting the value as 0 for each subcategory/range).